# Higher dimensional polygonal numbers formula

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, arithmetic

The general formula for the $m$-th $n$-gonal number is given by
$$P_n(m) = \frac{m^2(n-2)-m(n-4)}{2}$$

So, to give quick examples:

Triangular numbers ($n=3$):
$$P_3(m) = \frac{m^2+m}{2}$$

Square numbers ($n=4$):
$$P_4(m) = m^2$$

Pentagonal numbers ($n=5$):
$$P_5(m) = \frac{3m^2-m}{2}$$

And so on...

Wikipedia mentions [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Figurate_number) a generalization to higher dimensions when considering the dots as $r$-dimensional balls. $r=2$ would give us polygonal numbers, $r=3$ would give us polyhedral numbers, etc. Let's denote this as $P^r_n(m)$, my question is whether there is a general formula for $P^r_n(m)$. It seems that many different sources use different terminology that sometimes contradicts one another, so I haven't been able to find any such formula. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: One issue here may be definitions. In $2$ dimensions, $P_4(m)$ give the square numbers. But in $3$ dimensions, are the cubic numbers $P^3_4(m)$ or $P^3_6(m)$? How does one define the non-triangular figurate numbers in more dimensions? Can we define the hexagonal-close packed numbers in three dimensions, and are they labeled $P^3_{12}(m)$? I think trying to generalize to higher-order figurates other than the simplex and the $n$-cube is just not going to work.

Comment: You could of course generalize an $n$-gon to an $n$-gonal prism, which might lead you to $P_n^r(m) = (m+1)^{r-2} P_n(m)$.  Other than that, I don't think there is a natural way to generalize an $n$-gon to $\mathbb R^3$, let alone $\mathbb R^r$.

Comment: If you restrict to $r$-dimensional packings that can be discretized into $r-1$ dimensional layers, there's a possibility of recursive relations. For example, a pyramid is the sum of varying triangular layers, $P^3_4(m) = \sum_{m'=1}^m P^2_3(m')$, and a cube is a sum of constant square layers, $P^3_6(m) = \sum_{m'=1}^m P^2_4(m)$. Here I'm interpretting $n$ as number of $r-1$ dimensional faces in the $r$-dimensional packing.